# Error regarding libnvidia package when updating with apt upgrade

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, upgrade

I have a problem with `sudo apt upgrade` in Ubuntu 18.04 where I got this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-cfg1-430 : Conflicts: libnvidia-cfg1-any
 libnvidia-cfg1-440 : Conflicts: libnvidia-cfg1-any
 libnvidia-compute-430 : Conflicts: libcuda-10.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-10.0-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-10.1-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-10.1-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-5.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-5.0-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-5.5-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-5.5-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-6.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-6.0-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-6.5-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-6.5-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-7.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-7.0-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-7.5-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-7.5-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-8.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-8.0-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-9.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-9.0-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-9.1-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-9.1-1:i386
                         Conflicts: libcuda-9.2-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-9.2-1:i386
                         Conflicts: nvidia-opencl-icd
                         Conflicts: nvidia-opencl-icd:i386
                         Breaks: libnvidia-compute-430:i386 (!= 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-compute-430:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-compute-430 (!= 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
 libnvidia-compute-440 : Conflicts: libcuda-10.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-10.1-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-5.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-5.5-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-6.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-6.5-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-7.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-7.5-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-8.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-9.0-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-9.1-1
                         Conflicts: libcuda-9.2-1
                         Conflicts: nvidia-opencl-icd
 libnvidia-compute-440:i386 : Conflicts: libcuda-10.0-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-10.1-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-5.0-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-5.5-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-6.0-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-6.5-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-7.0-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-7.5-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-8.0-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-9.0-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-9.1-1
                              Conflicts: libcuda-9.2-1
                              Conflicts: nvidia-opencl-icd
 libnvidia-decode-430 : Conflicts: libnvidia-decode
                        Conflicts: libnvidia-decode:i386
                        Breaks: libnvidia-decode-430:i386 (!= 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-decode-430:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-decode-430 (!= 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
 libnvidia-decode-440 : Conflicts: libnvidia-decode
 libnvidia-decode-440:i386 : Conflicts: libnvidia-decode
 libnvidia-encode-430 : Conflicts: libnvidia-encode
                        Conflicts: libnvidia-encode:i386
                        Breaks: libnvidia-encode-430:i386 (!= 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-encode-430:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-encode-430 (!= 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
 libnvidia-encode-440 : Conflicts: libnvidia-encode
 libnvidia-encode-440:i386 : Conflicts: libnvidia-encode
 libnvidia-fbc1-430 : Conflicts: libnvidia-fbc1
                      Conflicts: libnvidia-fbc1:i386
                      Breaks: libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386 (!= 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-fbc1-430 (!= 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
 libnvidia-fbc1-440 : Conflicts: libnvidia-fbc1
 libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386 : Conflicts: libnvidia-fbc1
 libnvidia-gl-430 : Conflicts: libnvidia-gl
                    Conflicts: libnvidia-gl:i386
                    Breaks: libnvidia-gl-430:i386 (!= 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-gl-430:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-gl-430 (!= 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
 libnvidia-gl-440 : Conflicts: libnvidia-gl
 libnvidia-gl-440:i386 : Conflicts: libnvidia-gl
 libnvidia-ifr1-430 : Conflicts: libnvidia-ifr1
                      Conflicts: libnvidia-ifr1:i386
                      Breaks: libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 (!= 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 : Breaks: libnvidia-ifr1-430 (!= 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 is to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-440 : Conflicts: libnvidia-ifr1
 libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386 : Conflicts: libnvidia-ifr1
 nvidia-compute-utils-430 : Conflicts: nvidia-persistenced
 nvidia-compute-utils-440 : Conflicts: nvidia-persistenced
 nvidia-dkms-430 : Conflicts: nvidia-dkms-kernel
                   Conflicts: nvidia-dkms-kernel:i386
 nvidia-dkms-440 : Conflicts: nvidia-dkms-kernel
                   Conflicts: nvidia-dkms-kernel:i386
 nvidia-kernel-source-430 : Conflicts: nvidia-kernel-source
 nvidia-kernel-source-440 : Conflicts: nvidia-kernel-source
 nvidia-utils-430 : Conflicts: nvidia-smi
                    Conflicts: nvidia-utils
 nvidia-utils-440 : Conflicts: nvidia-smi
                    Conflicts: nvidia-utils
 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430 : Conflicts: nvidia-driver-binary
                                 Conflicts: xorg-driver-binary
 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440 : Conflicts: nvidia-driver-binary
                                 Conflicts: xorg-driver-binary
E: Broken packages
```

It looks like the main culprit is the nvidia package.
I installed `nvidia-driver-430` through apt in which I have locked it with `sudo apt-mark hold nvidia-driver-430`. Then I installed Cuda 10 and CuDNN through the nvidia website (not through `apt`). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: your issue (putting aside any issue with using upstream cuda) is that you installed the 430 driver (430.50-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) a long time ago,  locked it and then likely never tried to update. In Ubuntu the 430 driver packages are now all transitional packages that install the corresponding 440 packages.  (locking a meta package is not a good thing to do anyway.)   Unlock the 430 meta and update to 440 packages and deal with fallout with cuda or unlock, add the graphics driver ppa and update it's actual 430 driver packages to 430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1

Comment: Your best bet is to remove the lock, update sources and see what happens then..

Answer (score 0):

Followed @doug comment.

I just unhold the nvidia-driver package and update my CUDA and CuDNN installation. That solves the problem.